# Running various commands within an async task

Tags: c#, architecture

I have a static class and within that class is an async task that runs continuously processing set commands against a serial port. If I expose a public class to programmers that includes methods and properties what would be the best way to have those to be executed on demand within the async task?  How would I trigger something in the async task to accept and run the various commands?   Is there a pattern or an obvious way to do this?

The reason I'm doing it this because I want to run all commands from the same thread as the Task.  Some commands are predetermined and built into the task, others are from an outside environment like scripts or a com object, but they all go to the same serial port and need to be processed in a safe way.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a standard producer-consumer problem. Producers provide  commands, and the consumer is the task that handles them. Try to look up examples and documentation on how to achieve that in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example of producer-consumer

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private CancellationTokenSource _cts;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Producer()
    {
        var id = 0;
        while (true )
        {
            CommandPool.Commands.Add($"Command {++id}");

            Thread.Sleep(500);

            if (_cts.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                CommandPool.Commands.CompleteAdding();
                break;
            }
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("Producer finished");

    }

    private void Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CommandsComsumer.Run(_cts.Token);

        Task.Run(() => Producer(), _cts.Token);
    }

    private void Stop(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _cts.Cancel();
    }
}

public static class CommandPool
{
    public static readonly BlockingCollection<string> Commands = new BlockingCollection<string>();
}

public static class CommandsComsumer
{
    private static CancellationToken _token;

    public static Task Run(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _token = cancellationToken;
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(Consume, cancellationToken);
    }

    private static void Consume()
    {
        foreach (var cmd in CommandPool.Commands.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(cmd);
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("Consumer finished");

    }
}
```

Comment: let me check into this for any follow up questions, but it looks interesting, thanks!